# For loop not running more than one time

Tags: pine-script

I want to open trades only at specific datetimes, so I created this code:

```
var string[] dates = array.from("22/03/2023", "23/03/2023")

for i = 0 to array.size(dates) - 1
    var string[] date_obj = str.split(array.get(dates, i), "/")
    if str.tostring(dayofmonth) == array.get(date_obj, 0) and str.tostring(month) == array.get(date_obj, 1) and str.tostring(year) == array.get(date_obj, 2) and hour == 14     and minute > 50 and strategy.opentrades == 0
        strategy.entry(id = 'Short Entry', direction = strategy.short)
```

The problem is that only one trade is opened, on 22nd of march. No matter how many other dates I add to the array, it's always just the first one that's processed in the for loop. What mistake am I doing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are trying to open all orders in one direction, then you need to enable pyramiding for the strategy. This is a parameter `pyramiding` of the `strategy()` function, it is used to set number of orders that can be opened in one direction.
2. Your condition `strategy.opentrades == 0` indicates that the order should only be opened if there are no other open orders. it needs to be removed to get the result you describe when multiple orders are opened.
3. When you cast the month to the string `str.tostring(month)`, the third month will be given as '3', you have months in the array as '03', so when comparing these two strings, the result will be `false`.
4. Your inner array `date_obj` is declared as `var`, so only the first element is assigned to it, because var variables are intended for single initialization. Therefore, only the first date from the array `dates` will always be checked.
5. Recommendations: you can remove from the `dates` array dates on which orders have already been executed, so as not to check them again when they are no longer needed and immediately exit from loop.
   Here is an example code with fixed bugs:

   ```
   //@version=5
   strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, pyramiding=2)

   var string[] dates = array.from("20/3/2023", "24/3/2023")

   for date in dates
       string[] date_obj = str.split(date, "/")
       if str.tostring(dayofmonth) == array.get(date_obj, 0) and str.tostring(month) == array.get(date_obj, 1) and str.tostring(year) == array.get(date_obj, 2)
           strategy.entry(id = 'Short Entry', direction = strategy.short)
           dates.remove(dates.indexof(date))
           break
   ```

Here `pyramiding=2` means strategy cannot open more than two trades in one direction. You can change this value to what is required in your case.